# Combining if and or

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am having difficulties creating this formula in Google Sheets. I have columns D,E,F with the headers:
Should  Actual  Diff.
Under D and E a drop down with Top Expert, Professional, Working Knowledge, Awareness of

I want the following conditions:

If "Top Expert" and "Top Expert" then "No Need"

If "Top Expert" and "Professional" then "Slight Need"

If "Top Expert" and "Working Knowledge" then "Need"

If "Top Expert" and "Awareness of" then "Strong Need"

If "Professional" and "Top Expert" then "No Need"

If "Professional" and "Professional then "No Need"

If "Professional" and "Working Knowledge" then "Slight Need"

If "Professional" and "Awareness of" then "Need"

If "Working Knowledge" and "Top Expert" then "No Need"

If "Working Knowledge" and "Professional then "No Need"

If "Working Knowledge" and "Working Knowledge" then "No Need"

If "Working Knowledge" and "Awareness of" then "Slight Need"

If "Awareness of" and "Top Expert" then "No Need"

If "Awareness of" and "Professional then "No Need"

If "Awareness of" and "Working Knowledge" then "No Need"

If "Awareness of" and "Awareness of" then "No Need"

I was able to create ONE formula for just one but then it stopped working

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gtykc0ipLIjIB1YziwmGUAwQC7XqfeZ71-6Sfgw91f8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Justin, welcome on WE ! Good pratice is to provide a dummy sheet with some data in it and make sure that we're able to edit.

Comment: [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/447561/how-to-use-the-and-and-or-functions-in-google-sheets/) reference should get you started.

Comment: @User24601 I used that link originally but it didn't help.

Comment: @Jacob Jan Tuinstra What do you mean? A Screenshot? ATM there is no content/formula in the cells.

Comment: "And ignoring 'NA'" does not make sense to me. Something needs to happen if 'NA' is chosen for Column D or Column E. And since you've listed only what should happen with two-part combos, it remains unclear what should happen if D or E is 'NA' (or if both are). Please clarify.

Comment: @Erik Tyler. I see. I will simply remove NA from the drop down and leave it blank if it doesn't apply.

Comment: I disagree with @JacobJanTuinstra regarding allowing anyone to edit b/c changes made by people intending to help could make harder to others to find the "original" state of the spreadsheet. Instead share it to anyone is able to view.

Comment: The link in the questions points to a spreadsheet that requires to ask for access. Share it with anyone with the link to have more chances that people look at it, by the other hand, it's better to add a sample of the data input and the intended result directly in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your drop-downs run from D2:D and E2:E and that you want to process for F2:F entirely, make sure F2:F is entirely empty and then add the following to F2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(D2:D&E2:E="",,IFERROR(IF(LEFT(D2:D)="A","No Need",IF(LEFT(D2:D)="W",IF(LEFT(E2:E)="A","Slight Need","No Need"),IF(LEFT(D2:D)="P",IF(LEFT(E2:E)="A","Need",IF(LEFT(E2:E)="W","Slight Need","No Need")),IF(LEFT(D2:D)="T",VLOOKUP(LEFT(E2:E),{"A","Strong Need";"W","Need";"P","Slight Need";"T","No Need"},2,FALSE),)))))))`

I'm not going to explain the logic of this, since that is outlined in your original post.

There are a few parts of note, however:

`LEFT(D2:D)` etc.

This is one way to get the first character of a string, which shortens the formula as compared with typing out the whole key word or phrase each time. We can do this only because the first letter of each of your key words/phrases is unique.

`(...)*(...)`

This means both elements must return TRUE. It's the array version of AND(... , ...).

`{"A","Strong Need";"W","Need";"P","Slight Need";"T","No Need"}`

This is a virtual array, where comma denotes "to the right" and semicolon denotes "underneath."